# Help understanding intermediate steps in this calculus

Tags: calculus

Textbook: Numerical methods for engineers and scientits - 7th edition - Chapra&Canale.

I have just started reading this book, and I believe the author skipped the intermediate steps for the reader to figure out. I am having difficulty understanding:

This is my progress so far from Eqn(1.9) from there on I cant figure out how to reach Eqn(1.10)

```
Eqn: 1.9
dv/dt = g - (c.v/m)
dv/dt = (gm/c)[1-(cv/mg)]
```

From here on I cant understand how to proceed to Eqn 1.10.

[Check text here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzBHk.jpg)

PS: This stackexchange uses MathJax, its shut down on April 30th 2017. Any alternative?

Comment: **Hint:** This is a Separable Equation, so separate and integrate and we end up solving (note the IC, $v(0) = 0$):  $$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{g - \dfrac{c v}{m}}~dv = \int ~dt$$

Comment: They solved the first order ODE in that step.  Equation 1.9 is an equation in which the first derivative of some function is equal to a constant plus the function itself.  Are you familiar with differential equations?

Comment: @Moo : So I followed through your hint and I' have gone through so far. However, I am still missing something. May be some simple thing. A $[gm/c]$ term for the exponent term.

$$t = \frac{-m}{c}.Log[gm-cv]\Rightarrow -\frac{ct}{m}=Log[gm-cv]\Rightarrow v = \frac{gm}{c}-e^{-\frac{ct}{m}}$$

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky yes I am learning concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this way to get the solution v(t) to this DE.

Hint : let $U(t) = e^{(ct/m)}$

We have: 
$\frac{dv}{dt} + \frac{c}{m}.v$ = g

We multiply the DE by **u(t)**, we get :

$\frac{ dv}{dt}.(e^{ct/m)} + \frac{c}{m}.v . e^{ct/m} = g . e^{ct/m}$

Notice that : $\frac{ dv}{dt}.(e^{ct/m)} + \frac{c}{m}.v . e^{ct/m} = \frac{d(v(t).e^{ct/m})}{dt}$

Thus : $d(v(t).e^{ct/m}) = g . e^{ct/m}.dt$

Meaning :

$v(t).e^{ct/m} = \int{g . e^{ct/m}.dt}$

$v(t).e^{ct/m} = \frac {gm}{c}.e^{ct/m} + C$

$v(t) = \frac {gm}{c} + C.e^{-ct/m}$

Now we have v(0) = 0 as a way to find the C :

$v(0)=0$ meaning : $v(0) = \frac {gm}{c} + C = 0$

Thus : $ C = -\frac {gm}{c}$

Concluding : $v(t) = \frac {gm}{c} - \frac {gm}{c}.e^{-ct/m}$

Now, sorry for any mistakes as writing in this site is tricky for me, my first time posting:/

Answer (score 0):

We start out with $$\frac{dv}{dt}=g-\frac{c v}{m}$$ and then get $$dv=\left(g-\frac{c v}{m}\right)dt$$ and

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{g - \dfrac{c v}{m}}~dv = \int ~dt$$ Next, we perform $u$-substitution by setting $u=g-\frac{c v}{m}$. That means $du=-\frac{c}{m}dv$ and $dv=-\frac{m}{c}du$. Thus, our integral becomes $$-\frac{m}{c}\int \dfrac{1}{u}~du=\int~dt$$ which can be simplified to $$-\frac{m}{c} \ln {\lvert u\rvert}=t+C$$ where $C$ is the constant of integration. This in turn simplifies to $$\ln {\lvert u\rvert}^{-m/c}=t+C$$ This equation can be rewritten as $$e^{\ln {\lvert u\rvert}^{-m/c}}=e^{t+C}$$ or equivalently $$u^{-m/c}=Ce^t$$ By plugging the value for $u$ back into the equation, we get $$\left(g-\frac{c v}{m}\right)^{-m/c}=Ce^t$$ Given that $t=0$ when $v=0$, we know that $C=g^{-m/c}$. So now our equation becomes $$\left(g-\frac{c v}{m}\right)^{-m/c}=g^{-m/c}e^t$$ which can be rewritten as $$\left(\frac{g}{g-\frac{cv}{m}}\right)^{m/c}=e^t$$ and then can be rewritten as $$\frac{g}{g-\frac{cv}{m}}=e^{ct/m}$$ or equivalently as $$g-\frac{g}{e^{ct/m}}=\frac{cv}{m}$$ meaning that $$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{v(t)=\frac{gm}{c}\left(1-e^{(-c/m)t}\right)}$$